# How do I set path to respective bin of the mingw directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, clang, mingw

I'm trying to use C++ in VSCode, and I found a tutorial where I install g++ and clang to make it work.

I installed g++ fine, and added it to my list of environment variables, but then the instructions for installing clang say to "set path to respective bin of the mingw directory" without showing me how.

What does this mean and how do I do that?

Also, `#include <iostream>` looks like it doesn't work either, it says the file is not found, so I'm wondering if it's because clang isn't installed or something else I need to fix. Thanks!

Comment: If you add a link to the tutorial, we can see the quoted text in context.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smUzCvqQKC8&pbjreload=10 This is the link to the tutorial

Comment: @ScottMcPeak I'm not too sure how to share comments on youtube but to most of the questions about clang that are asked he responnds with "Install LLVM from here: http://releases.llvm.org/download.html (Pre-built binary is recommended)
After installation just set path to respective bin of the mingw directory. If you don't know how to set path search on the internet, you'll get a plenty of suggestion. 
Good luck!"

Comment: Where exactly in that video?  What time offset?

Comment: @ScottMcPeak He doesn't say anything about clang in the video, just in the description says to install it. And when someone asked in the comments about clang, he would respond with that comment

Comment: @ScottMcPeak  https://imgur.com/OIy2vuL   Here's the screenshot of the commment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've skimmed that tutorial video and YouTube comment section.  Basically I think it's a poor tutorial, as it doesn't explain the basics, and that's why you're getting tripped up.  My first recommendation is to save yourself some trouble and follow the [VSCode Getting Started with C++ Tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) instead.

Not only is the official tutorial easier to understand, it will guide you toward using the Microsoft C++ extension that almost everyone uses (and can help you with), rather than the comparatively obscure Clang-based C++ extension.

But that's not answer to your actual question.  You asked:

> ... the instructions for installing clang say to "set path to respective bin of the mingw directory" without showing me how.
>
> What does this mean and how do I do that?

I'm not sure!  It's sort of nonsensical.  But I **think** what is meant is:

1. Install mingw GCC and put its `bin` directory on the `PATH`.
2. Install LLVM+Clang and put its `bin` directory on the `PATH`.
3. Start VSCode from a shell where both are on the `PATH`.
4. Then proceed with the linked tutorial.

You say you already have mingw GCC on your path, but let's check that.  At the command prompt (I assume you are using the default Windows `cmd.exe` shell), run:

```
> gcc --version
gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

If you don't see output like that, then something is wrong.  Make sure the `bin` directory of mingw GCC, which contains `gcc.exe`, is on your `PATH`.

Next, Clang.  Clang is part of LLVM.  Wherever you installed LLVM, there should be a `bin` directory inside it containing `clang.exe`.  Add that to your `PATH`.  In my case, I installed LLVM into `d:\opt\llvm-8.0.1`, so I would run:

```
> set PATH=%PATH%;d:\opt\llvm-8.0.1\bin
```

Then check that it is working:

```
> clang --version
clang version 8.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_801/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: D:\opt\llvm-8.0.1\bin
```

Once both `gcc --version` and `clang --version` respond similarly to what I have shown, you're ready to start VSCode:

```
> code
```

and from there, the tutorial's instructions should work.

Comment: Thanks so much for this response!!

Comment: So I tried everything you said right here and followed the tutorial but for some reason when I type in #include <iostream>, it still says the file is not found!! Why is that? I'll be trying out the official tutorial you mentioned instead of this clang stuff, but do you know why it's doing this?

Comment: I don't know.  If it's still not working, and you want to pursue it, I suggest posting another question after doing the usual googling.

Comment: Hm okay will do. Lastly, the "code" command doesn't work in my CMD. I tried googling and put the VSCode bin path in my environment path but that still didn't fix it. Also tried setting Windows CMD as my default in the command pallet through VSCode...

Comment: Ok so I finally got the "code ." command to work, just had to restart the CMD haha

Comment: Hi @ming if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue a while back. Go to the installation directory of mingw/bin. copy this path and add it to the environment variable PATH to your Windows system, save it. Relaunch vscode and then try pressing ctrl + ` and execute code using g++. This way gdb will also work.

Comment: I already did that for mingw/bin, I just need to somehow install clang correctly..